# updating value in laravel using api call

Tags: php, mysql, api, laravel

I have been trying to update the handicap score using a post request. But I seem to get an error saying : creating default object from empty value.

Code :

```
public function handicap(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $rules = array(
            'handicap'            => 'required'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // process the login
        if ($validator->fails()) 
        {
            return response()->json(['msg' => 'Failed to update Handicap score!'], 200);
        } 
        else {

            if(Handicap::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->exists())
            {
                $handicap                 = Handicap::find($user->id);
                $handicap->user_id        = $user->id;
                $handicap->handicap       = $request->input('handicap');
                $handicap->save();
                return response()->json(['msg' => 'You have successfully updated your handicap score!'], 200);
            }
            else
            {
                $handicap = new Handicap;
                $handicap->user_id        = $user->id;
                $handicap->handicap       = $request->input('handicap');
                $handicap->save();
                return response()->json(['msg' => 'You have added your handicap score successfully!'], 200);
            }

        }
    }
```

If user does not exist in Handicap table then the else block code runs and creates a handicap score for the user else the if block needs to execute and update the score. I tried many alternatives but dont seem to get it working. Dont know what am I doing wrong.

I checked the $user, $handicap variables using return. those variables have the info that I need to add to the table. Its just that Its not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably comes from the line you have `Handicap::find($user->id)`. Obviously it's null, because such model was not found, even though your if statement returns `true`.

In your `if` statement you have `where('user_id' , '=', $user->id)`, but you are using `Handicap::find($user->id)` which is basically `Handicap::where('id', '=', $user->id)->first()`.

Try changing it to:

`$handicap = Handicap::where('users_id', '=', $user->id)->first();`

Answer (score 0):

You may give this a try:

```
public function handicap(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        'handicap' => 'required'
    ]);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'Failed to update Handicap score!'], 200);
    }

    $handicap = Handicap::firstOrNew([
        'user_id' => $request->user()->id;
    ]);
    $handicap->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $handicap->handicap = $request->handicap;
    $handicap->save();

    return response()->json(['msg' => 'You have successfully updated your handicap score!'], 200);
}
```

Comment: Is `$request->handicap` a shorthand for `$request->input('handicap')` or just a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo.. all the request inputs can be accessed as class properties

Comment: I get this error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`usg`.`handicaps`, CONSTRAINT `handicaps_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `handicaps` (`handicap`) values (66))

Comment: I've updated the answer.. the user_id should be added as well